# Import rss file into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, parsing

I have the following code that imports the xml data (items) to Excel.

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim rCount As Long
Dim XMLHttpRequest As XMLHTTP
Dim response As String
Dim URL As String
Dim sTemperature As String
Dim xNode As Object
Dim items As Object
Dim FieldIndex As Long
Dim ItemIndex As Long
Dim Node
Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rCount = 2
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, 13).Value = Array("ID", "Title", "Link", "Description", "Product Type 1", "Product Type 2", "Image Link", "Availability", "Price", "Sale Price", "Identifier Exists", "Shipping Weight", "Custom Label")
    Dim xDoc        As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xEmpDetails As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xEmployee   As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild      As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xDoc.async = False
xDoc.validateOnParse = False
xDoc.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.rss")


Set xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//channel")

Dim strValue As String

For FieldIndex = 3 To xNode.ChildNodes.Length
    c = 1
        Set items = xNode.ChildNodes(FieldIndex)
        If Not items Is Nothing Then
            For ItemIndex = 0 To items.ChildNodes.Length - 1
                If ItemIndex >= 1 Then

                Set Node = items.ChildNodes(ItemIndex)
                Sheet1.Cells(rCount, c).Value = FrontClean(EndClean(Node.nodeTypedValue))
                c = c + 1
                End If
            Next ItemIndex

        End If

        rCount = rCount + 1

Next FieldIndex
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Function FrontClean(param As String) As String
Dim b()     As Byte
Dim i       As Long

b = param
For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2
    Select Case b(i)
        Case 0 To 32, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157
        Case Else: Exit For
    End Select
Next i

FrontClean = Mid$(param, (i + 2) \ 2)
End Function

Function EndClean(param As String) As String
Dim b()     As Byte
Dim i       As Long

b = param

For i = UBound(b) - 1 To 0 Step -2
    Select Case b(i)
        Case 0 To 32, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157
        Case Else: Exit For
    End Select
Next i

EndClean = Left$(param, (i + 2) \ 2)
End Function
```

The results should be in 13 columns but I got extra columns.

I think that's because some nodes like product_type may be there more than once.

Here's a snapshot
[image]

Here's a link to the sample file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/mym24lljt04us3o/Sample.rss/file

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code, figure out where you're not parsing properly, and fix it.

Comment: As you loop through the  child nodes on each "row" , you need to track the element names and which Excel column they map to (a Dictionary seems like a good choice here...), otherwise as you're now seeing you will not be able to arrange "same" elements together.   Even if you have different order of elements within different rows, without duplicates, your current code doesn't account for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I have spent hours trying to figure it out but I there is no use. Can you help me fixing it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above - you can track the column locations for each field, so you can manage duplicate fields or fields in different orders.

Tested:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rCount As Long, c As Long
    Dim XMLHttpRequest As XMLHTTP
    Dim itemNode As Object, itemNodes As Object, fieldNode As Object
    Dim dict As Object, elName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rCount = 2

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.validateOnParse = False
    xDoc.Load "C:\Stuff\Sample.rss"

    c = 1
    Set itemNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//channel/item")

    For Each itemNode In itemNodes '<< loop over items
        For Each fieldNode In itemNode.ChildNodes '<< loop over item fields
            'ignore comment nodes etc
            If fieldNode.NodeType = NODE_ELEMENT Then

                elName = fieldNode.BaseName '<< get the tag name
                'Check if we've not seen this tag name before
                '  if new then assign it a column number
                If Not dict.exists(elName) Then
                    dict.Add elName, c
                    ws.Cells(1, c).Value = elName
                    c = c + 1
                End If

                'put the node value in the correct column
                '  (add to previous value if duplicate tag)
                With ws.Cells(rCount, dict(elName))
                    .Value = .Value & IIf(.Value <> "", ";", "") & _
                              FrontClean(EndClean(fieldNode.nodeTypedValue))
                End With

            End If
        Next fieldNode
        rCount = rCount + 1

    Next itemNode

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome solution. You are a legend
Can I ask some questions as I need to learn more. First as for the variable 'itemNodes' is declared as object. What if I need to use early binding how can I declare this variable in that case? .. I tried 'As msxml2.IXMLDOMNode' but this gives me error

Comment: I have played around and found that 'As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList' is working well. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you use a breakpoint to halt the execution after itemNodes is set, you can enter `? typename(itemNodes)` in the immediate pane and it will give you `IXMLDOMSelection`

Comment: Please bear me. Second question why in this line `xDoc.async = False` set to False and what's the benefit of it?

Comment: But why using As msxml2.IXMLDOMNode works !! although it is 'IXMLDOMSelection'?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms761398   You would not use `True` unless you had code to check the loading progress.  With `False` your code waits till loading is complete before continuing.

Comment: Don't ask me!  I'm not that familiar with the class/interface names within MSXML; that's why I often use `As Object`...

Comment: Thank you very much for great and awesome help. Best Regards